# Why does ssh allocate a tty on server side?

Tags: ssh, tty, sshd, pty

Basically when you run an interactive program on the server you need to use `ssh -t` instead of `ssh`. For example:

- This works: `ssh -t user@server top`.
- This doesn't work: `ssh user@server top`.

Question is: Why does ssh need a server-side tty for such programs? Is it possible to directly pipe data streams between the server program and the client side tty?

---

To add some details, we know the tty can multiplex stdout and stderr onto a single stream. This means if you run `ssh -t` then on the client side you won't be able to tell the difference between stdout and stderr, and to pipe them separately. Therefore I think a server-side tty in between breaks some of kind of transparency. It'd be nice if ssh makes running server-side programs exactly the same experience as if those programs were local.

Comment: Related - https://serverfault.com/questions/593399/what-is-the-benefit-of-not-allocating-a-terminal-in-ssh.

Comment: @slm I saw this one, but it was answering why without `-t` is better than with `-t`, kind of the opposite to this question.

Comment: Yeah it's the opposite of your Q but in explaining the reverse explains your Q, at least IMO.

Comment: The explanation in that question favors without `-t`, but the fact is, there is `-t`, so there must something not covered in that question that favors `-t`, right?

Comment: "a server-side tty in between breaks some of kind of transparency. It'd be nice if ssh makes running server-side programs exactly the same experience as if those programs were local." – Please see my Q&A pair: [`ssh` with separate stdin, stdout, stderr AND tty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/653431/108618).